# UISearchController's UISearchBar does not apply customizations initially

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have been in the hell of trying to customize `UISearcBar`. The application i am working on supports iOS 11+ and so I decided to separate the customization process for above and below iOS 13. Here is the subclass of `UISearchController` I am using;

```
class SearchController: UISearchController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                print()
                self.searchBar.tintColor = .richBlueTwo
                self.searchBar.barTintColor = .white
                self.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .richBlueTwo
                self.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .white
            } else {
                self.searchBar.tintColor = .white
                self.searchBar.barTintColor = .white
                let searchTextField = self.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
                searchTextField?.textColor = .white
                self.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "iconSearch"), for: .search, state: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage in a `Controller`;

```
private var searchController = SearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    
}
```

The problem I am facing is when initially the controller is loaded and appeared, these changes has been made does not have any affect in UI until `UISearchBar` is activated. When there is tap or click on the search bar, colors and images are instantly changing to what they had been set.

Other weird thing is , initially status bar is `lightContent`. Strangely, the following sequence keeps happening;

1. `UISearchBar` is activated the first time. Status bar stays white
2. `UISearchBar` resignedFirstResponder(Cancel, clear buttons or tapped into the tableview). Status bar becomes black text
3. `UISearchBar` is activated again. Status bar becomes white again.
4. Afterwards whenever the bar is activated status bar content is light, otherwise dark

Any guesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make all this changes in the `viewWillAppear` function.

*** EDIT:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        searchBar.tintColor = .darkGray
        searchBar.placeholder = "Type movie title... "
        searchBar.barTintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.center = view.center
    }
```

Comment: @Faruk I edited my answer try it like that. It worked for me.

Comment: I just gave a shot to `viewDidAppear` and it worked. I will give this a shot as well. As you say this work, I am gonna accept this answer.